# HTML5 Custom error message not displaying in Firefox 53

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following code to display custom messages with form validation:

```
<input id="rulesRegulations1" name="rulesRegulations" title="Error" x-moz-errormessage="Error." oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('My custom error message.');" required="required" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){};" value="Y" type="checkbox">
```

Custom messages display fine in Chrome and IE but not Firefox 53. Anybody has any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @MaxZoom: snippet and setCustomValidity content included in code snippet included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The [validation error bug](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2017/form-validation-error-messages-disappear-quickly/) has been fixed with Firefox 53.0.2 shipped today.

Comment: Many thanks for that Kohei. Unfortunately, Firefox 53 is the version currently installed on machines across my institution so updating isn't an option. I suppose we'll have to just manage until they (IT) decide to roll out a new update. Thanks again.